# Is it normal to have Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException exceptions in production?

Tags: symfony

In our production logs we can see some exceptions like `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException`. We have errors and we will fix them, but what bothers me is that those are "Debug" classes.

We are running in the "prod" environment, is it normal to have "**debug**" exceptions? Or did we misconfigure something?

Comment: check the line in `app.php`.  Should read `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` The 2nd argument being debug status.

Comment: @DevDonkey the kernel is indeed created with debug being `false`. So you confirm that this is not "normal"? (i.e. in production that exception class shouldn't be used)

Comment: looking through our production logs (Sym 2.8.3), we have FatalThrowableException calls in it too.  Looking through the core code it looks to me like its just part of the logging system, that happens to reside in the `Symfony\Component\Debug` namespace.  Personally, I'd say you were ok.

Comment: @DevDonkey OK thank you for checking in your logs I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the framework bundle, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6eb5f93918d833954ca87c21900c5831e424f9a9/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/FrameworkBundle.php#L66 : `ErrorHandler::register(null, false)->throwAt($this->container->getParameter('debug.error_handler.throw_at'), true);`

It is deliberate, here is the discussion about it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11053

Answer (score -1):

Having exceptions is something different than having debug logging enabled.

Basically the `logger` service always is available in the `container`. You can always use it to add important information about the code that is executed. It would be wise to have different logging configurations per environment. The `prod` environment for example does not have to log 404 errors, but maybe you do want log that on `test` environments? You can exclude that in your `config_prod.yml`. See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog_regex_based_excludes.html

Aside of the actual logging, `monolog` can send you emails if a certain threshold has been reached. On `prod` you can let `monolog` send emails with `action_level: critical` and for `test` you can get more emails with more info with `action_level: error`. By setting `level` you can set the minimum level a log message should be to be included in the email. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog_email.html

Other recipes about logging can be found at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/index.html

To get back at the `debug` parameter and `Exception`, Symfony behaves differently with debugging enabled. For most standard applications the web toolbar and profiler are enabled, and if an exception is thrown, Symfony shows you an exception page. So basically, way more data is collected in `debug`. If debug is disabled, the `logger` still is in place though. Exceptions can always occur, because they are a result of uncaught application behavior (read: bugs). I'd advise to use the logger wisely to get emails that contain sufficient information to debug these exceptions.